# How to assign multidimensional coordinates in xarray

Tags: python, latitude-longitude, python-xarray

It seems from this source: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/examples/multidimensional-coords.html that it's possible to have multidimensional coordinates in an xarray dataset.

How do you assign such a multidimenional coordinates?

Let's say I have a dataset `ds` like this one:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:       (time_counter: 58, x: 1410, y: 945, z: 100)
Coordinates:
  * time_counter  (time_counter) datetime64[ns] 1999-11-01 ... 1999-12-27
Dimensions without coordinates: x, y, z
Data variables:
    so            (time_counter, z, y, x) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(1, 100, 945, 1410), meta=np.ndarray>
```

And I want to specify that the x and y coordinates correspond to the multidimensional arrays `lat (x,y)` and `lon (x,y)`, two-dimensional arrays of size x and y. How would I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Does `da.assign_coords(('x', 'y'), 2d_array)` do what you want?

Comment: @Maximilian, when I try so it renders the error `TypeError: assign_coords() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`.

Comment: Are you sure you're entering like the example? That only has 2 args; the first is a tuple

Comment: Yes I'm sure. The error does surprise me too.

Comment: Sorry — my mistake; the correct form is `da.assign_coords(new_dim=(('x', 'y'), 2d_array))`